# Not able to load image using img element in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Api: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Canberra,Australia&appid=8d2de98e089f1c28e1a22fc19a24ef04&units=metric

Image Source I want to load:
http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/10d@2x.png

Code used:

```
<img
  src={
    'http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/' +
    {this.state.weatherdata.weather[0].icon} +
    '@2x.png'
  }
></img>
```

Comment: You need to remove `{` and `}` around `this.state.weatherdata.weather[0].icon`. `this.state.weatherdata.weather[0].icon` is a string. And you only need `+` to concatenate the strings.

Comment: thank you.. it is working now using 'http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/'+this.state.weatherdata.weather[0].icon+'@2x.png'

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the following?

```
console.log('http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/'+{this.state.weatherdata.weather[0].icon}+'@2x.png'})
```

Try to console it since I dont know the details of this I cant help you, there should be a problem with your string

Comment: I am not able to console it. It says ':' expected.ts(1005)

Comment: can you make us a favor and send us all the code

Comment: just removed { } and it is working fine.. thanks to @ajeet Shah